# Remove ID in URL

Tags: url, siteurl, id

is it possible to remove ID in post URL :

https://www.example.com/example/example-2/exampleexample-2464942

I mean "2464942". Thanks everyone !

Comment: Can you explain what you try to do? Where does this URL come from?

Comment: This is a sample URL but my structure looks like this. I want to delete this ID at the end of URL to make it more SEO friendly @Johannes

Comment: And this is a single article link @Johannes

Comment: So you have a section of type structure? How does the entry URI format setting look like for that section?

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find URI format? Settings -> Routes ? @Johannes

Comment: There is a section settings page where you can find all sections.